# Trying to join AspNetUsers table in LINQ query results in Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Why am I not able to join my AspNetUsers table in a LINQ query ?

```
var query = (from O in _context.Organisations
                         join U in _context.Users on O.OrganisationId equals U.OrganisationId
                         where U.Id == userId
                         select new BudgetEntryVM
                         {
                             OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId,
                             OrganisationName = O.Name
                         }).ToList();
```

I get an error on the join :

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.
>
> Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

How else do I do this ?

Comment: Is this a runtime error?

Comment: Can you add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: no this isnt on runtime. I added the join and immediately gave the error

Comment: Can you post the type of `OrganisationId` of both tables?

Comment: On AspNetUsers Table it is nvarchar(max) and on Organisations table it is int :-/

Comment: I think you just found your problem ;-)

Comment: OK thats a bit of a noob move - I didnt realise the Data types were different(I took over from another developer). I fixed by changing U.OrganisationId to Convert.ToInt16(U.OrganisationId). Stefan, if you post that as the answer, I will mark it as the answer as you lead me to find the issue

Comment: Ha, I will. I am not sure for how long this question will stick around though ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.
>
> Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

states that there are no acceptable conversions in place for the given types, in your case: `O.OrganisationId` and `U.OrganisationId`.

Check the types and you will see they don't match.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! As I took over from another Developer, Id have expected him to make the datatypes the same... :-/ Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to convert both OrganisationId to string for join ?

Comment: Be careful when converting to int 'cause it could contain some caracters ;)

Comment: Generally I would agree, but in this case it will always be numeric. Thanks :)